# Check Constraint with Filtering Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I have a table that has bit column called "Flag" it does not allow NULL. A requirement here is to ALWAYS have `Flag=1` set for every Id in the table below but only 1 time per each unique Id and Flag columns combination. At the same time all other rows can be have `Flag=0` set multiple times if there are more than 1 entry.

Basically **SUM of Flag grouped by ID should always be 1.**

I though of unique constraint on the Id and Flag fields but since `Flag=0` can be set multiple times for the same combination this cannot be used.

Any suggestions?

**-- current dataset**

```
drop table if exists #test;
go
create table #Test (Id_pk int identity(1,1) not null, id int not null, Flag bit not null)
Insert into #Test (id, Flag) 
values (12, 0), (12,0), (12, 0), (12,0),  (12, 1), (12,1), (13,0), (13, 0), (14,1), (14,1), (20,1),  (20,0), (30,1),  (40,0)
select * from #Test
```

**-- desired outcome**

```
drop table if exists #test;
go
create table #Test (Id_pk int identity(1,1) not null, id int not null, Flag bit not null)
Insert into #Test (id, Flag) 
values (12, 0), (12,0), (12, 0), (12,0),  (12, 0), (12,1), (13,0), (13, 1), (14,0), (14,1), (20,1),  (20,0), (30,1),  (40,1)
select * from #Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking for a `check` constraint.  You want a filtered unique constraint:

```
create unique index unq_test_id_flag
    on #test(id)
    where flag = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fafbd03f581b49090e8dc6eba4612faa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: to test your solution we should not be able to created such a unique constraint / index on the current data set table. Which is not the case...

Comment: @enigma6205 . . . Apologies.  I just put in the wrong syntax entirely.  It is now fixed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. I did not realize we can use covering index to achieve uniqueness !

Comment: We still allow ID to have Flag=0. Which is the actual challenge.

Comment: @enigma6205 . . . Yes, as in the DB Fiddle.